# Editing YAML documents in-place with Perl

Tags: perl, yaml

I am fairly new to Perl and YAML. I would like to read from a YAML file, and also edit/write some of the property values without rewriting the entire config file (preserving the existing comments, blank lines, spaces etc.)

I am using YAML library in Perl. What would be a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot readily write part of the file - you will end up rewriting the whole file.  If you did write a partial file, you'd have to seek to a start position, truncate the file to that length (or truncate then seek/append), and then write the new tail of the file after the unchanged start.  File systems do not support operations such as 'delete 329 bytes at offset 193 and insert 46 bytes after resulting offset 227'.

If your YAML module (library) preserves, or makes available, leading comments and blank lines somehow, then you'll be able to preserve them easily.  If not, then you'll probably have to do the job yourself - read and save the comment lines, then use YAML to parse the file, then write the preserved comments and the replacement YAML.

Comment: ah ok.. thanks mate... and you do have a keen eye for typos! :)